# Case Statement and NVL with Criteria API - IllegalArgumentException: The attribute [SingularAttributeImpmappings.DirectToFieldMapping

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, criteria, criteria-api

I am able to build criteria using JPA Criteria Builder

Java code snippet

```
cq.multiselect(root.get(ProductCatalogue_.userId),root.get(ProductCatalogue_.productList));

    Join<ProductCatalogue, ProductList> joinList = root.join(ProductCatalogue_.productList, JoinType.LEFT);
    Join<ProductCatalogue, ProductEmp> joinEmp = root.join(ProductCatalogue_.productEmp, JoinType.LEFT);
```

Problem I am facing here not sure how to use case statement with the above code and nvl which I have used in SQL

**Update 1**

```
criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get(ProductCatalogue_.userId),
root.get(ProductCatalogue_.productList),criteriaBuilder.selectCase().
when(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(ProductCatalogue_.prodId),"ZCX"),
rootPr.get(ProductList_.prodDesc + " # " + 
rootEmp.get(ProductEmp_.empNo))).otherwise(rootPr.get(ProductList_.prodDesc));
```

Exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The attribute [SingularAttributeImpl[org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[prodDesc-->PRODUCT_LISTS.prodDesc]]] from the managed type [EntityTypeImpl@3567635:ProductList [ javaType: class test.entity.ProductList descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(test.entity.ProductList --> [DatabaseTable(PRODUCT_LISTS)]), mappings: 5]] is not present.

**Update 2**

```
Expression<String> stringConcat = 
criteriaBuilder.concat(criteriaBuilder.concat(rootPr.get(ProductList_.prodDesc), " # "), 
rootEmp.get(ProductEmp_.empNo));
```

Error

> missing right parenthesis

because then part of SQL has a question mark as it is expecting a parameter

```
THEN (t0.prodDesc = ?)
```

Comment: In JPA criteria, NVL has an equivalent. `CriteriaBuilder.coalesce()`. CASE also has an equivalent: `CriteriaBuilder.selectCase()`

Comment: @NeilStockton I have tried using Case however it resulted in errors, I have updated my question with my Case statement and exception. Could you kindly have a look. Not sure whether my case statement in `multiselect` is correct or not!

Comment: @Ish I have tried using Case however it resulted in errors, I have updated my question with my Case statement and exception. Could you kindly have a look.

Comment: where is the "otherwise()" part of the CASE ? (i.e the ELSE)

Comment: @NeilStockton `otherwise()` I have put a string with hypen, I have updated question

Comment: I think you have forgotten a `)` after `rootPr.get(ProductList_.prodDesc`

Comment: @perissf  Do not have code at the moment to test what you have mentioned. If a parenthesis is missing, would it give a compiler error? Exception thrown doesn't mention about parenthesis.

Comment: At a first glance, this last error looks like a bug in the JPA implementation. Which JPA provider are you using? Can you test on another provider?

Comment: @perissf I am using EclipseLink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems here. First, [`Path#get(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Path.html#get(javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute)) needs an attribute name, therefore you can't pass the string concatenation. Second, if you want to select the result of a string concatenation, you have to use [`CriteriaBuilder#concat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#concat(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression)) instead of pure java strings concatenated using `+` operator.

Therefore I would try this:

```
Expression<String> stringConcat = criteriaBuilder.concat(
    criteriaBuilder.concat(rootPr.get(ProductList_.prodDesc), " # "), 
    rootEmp.get(ProductEmp_.empNo));

criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get(ProductCatalogue_.userId), 
    root.get(ProductCatalogue_.productList), 
    criteriaBuilder.selectCase()
        .when(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(ProductCatalogue_.prodId),"ZCX"), stringConcat)
        .otherwise(rootPr.get(ProductList_.prodDesc)));
```

Finally, the NVL part should be built using another `selectCase()` statement on a `CriteriaBuilder#isNull()` result:

```
Expression<Long> userId = criteriaBuilder.selectCase()
    .when(criteriaBuilder.isNull(rootEmp.get(ProductEmp_.userId)), root.get(ProductCatalogue_.userId))
    .otherwise(rootEmp.get(ProductEmp_.userId));
```

Comment: Is it `Path` or `Expression`?

Comment: I have tried with Path, however I was getting the following error `javax.persistence.criteria.Path<java.lang.String> expected but javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<java.lang.String> found` . So I have tried with `Expression`. I have updated my question with Expression code snippet.

Comment: Can you update your answer as I have used Expression instead of Path and I was able to get rid of missing parenthesis error.